# Ajax - живой поиск (проблемы с кодом)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Делал урок по Ajax поиску, когда вбиваю слово,оно должно проверяться через array в php файле и показывать есть ли оно или нет в array, но в результате почему то не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="process()">
    <h3>The chuf bla bla bla</h3>
    Enter food :

    <input type="text" id="userInput" />

    <div id="underInput" />
</body>
</html>
```

foodstore.php

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';

    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','beef','ham');

    if(in_array($food, $foodArray))
        echo 'We have '.$food.'!';
    elseif ($food=='') 
        echo 'Enter food idiot';
    else
        echo 'We do not have '.$food.'!';

echo '</response>';
 ?>
```

foodstore.js

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }


    if (!xmlHttp) 
        alert("cant creATE that obj");
    else
        return xmlHttp;

}


function process(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4) {

        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("useInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
        setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){

        if(xmlHttp.status==200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }else{
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в чем выражается `не работает.` ? ........ Скорее всего у вас доходит до сюда `echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';` отдает строку, а на остальное игнорируется.....нужно контент складывать в одну переменную и только потом её в конце отдавать.... либо буферизировать через `ob_start()`,  `ob_flush()`

Comment: но дело в то что в уроке именно так и делали,и там всё работало,а у меня только форму ввода отображает

Comment: Ну тогда у вас проблема в опечатке `encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("useInput")` должно быть `userInput` ............ и это вы могли бы увидеть просто открыв консоль и увидеть там ошибку...... консоль и дебаггер - ваши лучшие друзья, запомните это!)

Comment: кстати, нагружать сервер через setTimeout не самая лучшая идея

Answer (score 1):

В php-коде ошибок нет (хотя рекомендую почитать про `json` и использовать его вместо `xml`). А так же если после приведенного кода в `foodstore.php` делаются какие-нибудь операции, после `echo '</response>';` можете написать `exit();`.

Очень плохая практика отправлять каждую секунду запрос на сервер, если это не нужно. Нужно отправлять запрос (получать данные) только после изменения значения input, т.е. правильнее было бы повесить обрабочик на изменение значения:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    alert('input changed to: ', input.value);
    // только после изменения вызываем process
    process(input.value);
});
```

Функцию `createXmlHttpRequestObject` (если вам не нужна поддержка старых IE, < IE7) можно удалить и сделать так:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Функции `handleServerResponse` и `process` верны за исключением вызова `process` каждую секунду: `setTimeout('process()',1000);`. У body `onload="process()"` тоже нужно удалить.

HTML:

```
<div>Enter food : <input type="text" id="userInput" /></div>
<div id="underInput"></div>
```

JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    // alert('input changed to: ', input.value);
    process(input.value);
});

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
function process(inputValue) {
    var food = encodeURIComponent(inputValue);
    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'foodstore.php?food=' + food, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function handleServerResponse() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
    } else{
        alert('Something went wrong!');
    }
}
```

Также всегда можно посмотреть, что возвращает сервер (в Chrome - открыть панель для разработчика (`Ctrl+Shift+I`), перейти на вкладку `Network`).

И да, не читайте статьи с ресурса, где вы нашли этот урок, они очень устаревшие.